# Is the following proof of a limit valid?

Tags: calculus, logic

Although the following limit is extremely easy to prove but I want to know whether the following method is correct or not.
To prove

$$\lim_{x \to 5}  (x-1)^{1/2}=2$$
So I have to prove the following implication $$\forall \varepsilon >0 $$ $$\exists \delta >0 : 0<\left | x-5 \right |<\delta \Rightarrow |(x-1)^{1/2}-2|<\varepsilon$$

Thus I have to prove the above implication for all epsilon>0.
Now consider the following chain of arguments for all epsilon:-

$$|(x-1)^{1/2}-2|\geq \varepsilon\\
|(x-1)^{1/2}-2||(x-1)^{1/2}+2|\geq \varepsilon|(x-1)^{1/2}+2|\\
|x-5|\geq \varepsilon|(x-1)^{1/2}+2|\\
\nexists \delta >0 : 0<\left | x-5 \right |<\delta$$
The last implication follows from the one before that because $$|x-5|\geq \varepsilon|(x-1)^{1/2}+2|$$ for all epsilon means that |x-5| is not bounded above.
Thus this chain of arguments has made the following implication vacuous and hence true
 $$\exists \delta >0 : 0<\left | x-5 \right |<\delta \Rightarrow |(x-1)^{1/2}-2|<\varepsilon$$
Which was required to be proven. I asked one of my friends and he said that I cant consider my chain of arguments for all epsilon, but since epsilon is not a free variable and hence is a bounded variable thus the truth value of my first statement in the chain is either 0 or 1 and hence the reasoning is not flawed. 
Or am I applying logic absurdly and I am confused.
Kindly help.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you start with $|(x-1)^{1/2}-2|\geq \varepsilon$? You should've started with $|(x-1)^{1/2}-2|< \varepsilon$.

Comment: Arthur thank you for editing. I dont know to code that well so sorry for terribly posted question.

Comment: I started with $$not(|(x-1)^{1/2}|<\varepsilon)$$

Comment: @Arthur, but that would be starting with the *conclusion*! It looks to me like the OP is trying to prove the contrapositive (but not getting it quite right).

Comment: @syedsameedAhmed, the contrapositive here is a bit tricky, because the logical statement has three qualifiers: It's of the form $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta\forall x\ldots$.

Comment: @Barry Cipra, what would be the correct contrapositive?

Comment: @syedsameedAhmed The statement is not of the form $P \implies Q$, so it doesn't have a contrapositive, per se

Comment: Right. Anyway, it's _really_ common in any type of equation and inequality solving to start with what you ultimately want, and then simplify as much as you can to find what conditions let you have your conclusion. In this case, the common approach is to start with $|(x-1)^{1/2}-2|< \varepsilon$, and deduce what $\delta$ must be for that to hold. Adding an additional constraint, like $\delta<1$, and therefore $4<x<6$, is also pretty common in order to gain control over extra terms that appear, like $|(x-1)^{1/2}+2|$, which is now clearly smaller than, say, $5$ and larger than $3$.

Comment: @syedsameedAhmed, Y. Forman is quite correct, I'm mangling terminology.  I should have said it looks like you're attempting a proof by contradiction, assuming the negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown $(\forall\epsilon>0$, $|(x-1)^{1/2} - 2| \geq \epsilon) \implies |x-5|$ is not bounded above $\implies \not\exists\delta>0: 0 < |x-5| < \delta$

But you need to show $\forall\epsilon>0$, $(\exists\delta>0$, such that $(0 < |x-5| < \delta \implies |(x-1)^{1/2} - 2| < \epsilon))$

Notice the placement of the parentheses. Do you understand why what you showed is not logically equivalent?

Comment: Oh!! Thank you very much. My chain arguments although correct is not equivalent to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

For all those kind of continuity questions, you have to FIX $\epsilon >0$ and prove the existence of $\delta$ (that depends on the fixed $\epsilon$) such that for $0 < \vert x- x_0\vert < \delta$ you have $\vert f(x) - f(x_0) \vert < \epsilon$.

The good point that you noticed is that:
$$\vert \sqrt{x-1} - 2 \vert = \frac{(\sqrt{x-1} - 2 )(\sqrt{x-1} + 2)}{\sqrt{x-1} + 2}.$$

That helps a lot because now you can state that
$$\vert \sqrt{x-1} - 2 \vert = \left\vert \frac{x-5}{\sqrt{x-1} + 2}\right\vert.$$

As $\sqrt{x-1} \ge0$, you get
$$\vert \sqrt{x-1} - 2 \vert \le \frac{\vert x- 5 \vert}{2}$$ and you're done if you notice that when choosing $\delta = 2 \epsilon$, you get that
$$\vert \sqrt{x-1} - 2 \vert \le \frac{\vert x- 5 \vert}{2} < \epsilon$$ when
$\vert x-5\vert < \delta = 2 \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know this way and I had proved it in this way earlier. I dont understand why the approach provided in the question is wrong.